# In-place heapsort using std::collections::BinaryHeap

Tags: sorting, rust, heapsort

I'd like to create an in-place heapsort function in Rust. In the standard library I found `std::collections::BinaryHeap` that looked promising. I am able to use it to create a function consuming its argument:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;

fn heapsort<T: Ord>(list: Vec<T>) -> Vec<T> {
    let heap = BinaryHeap::from(list);
    heap.into_sorted_vec()
}
```

The docs state that "converting a vector to a binary heap can be done in-place", but I am having trouble creating one that works on a reference and can do it in-place (`heapsort<T: Ord>(list: &mut Vec<T>)`). Can I achieve it using only `std::collections::BinaryHeap`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am having trouble creating one that works on a reference and can do it in-place

`BinaryHeap` [is built on top of `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.11.0/src/libcollections/binary_heap.rs#L218-L220). When you create a new heap from a `Vec`, you have to give it complete ownership. It will then ensure that the vector is in a good state to act as a heap.

Since a `BinaryHeap` is not built on top of a `&mut Vec` (which would mostly have horrible ergonomics), you cannot do that.

It's unclear why you don't just use [`slice::sort`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.sort) on the vector.

> the docs state that "converting a vector to a binary heap can be done in-place"

To clarify, the documentation is correct - there's [no extra memory allocation needed](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.11.0/src/libcollections/binary_heap.rs#L1050-L1056), thus it is in-place. The important aspect is that the `BinaryHeap` **owns** its data and doesn't expose all the internals out to the world.

What you are asking for is the ability to call `rebuild` on a user-supplied vector. To me, this has dubious usefulness, but you could always submit an RFC to expose it.

Comment: I know about `slice::sort`. I just wanted to implement a heapsort (not necessarily from square one) and when I found `BinaryHeap` I thought I would give it a try. I was surprised that I couldn't make it work even though the docs state that "converting a vector to a binary heap can be done in-place". I though I was missing something.

Comment: @ljedrz: The "in-place" in this context refers to the buffer for the `Vec`'s elements. The `BinaryHeap` just takes ownership of the `Vec` and modifies it to have the heap structure.

Comment: Thanks @sellibitze; I though in-place implied I could do it directly on a mutable reference.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `mem::replace` for "moving" something out from behind a `&mut` reference:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::mem;

fn heapsort<T: Ord>(list: &mut Vec<T>) {
    let tmp = mem::replace(list, Vec::new());
    let heap = BinaryHeap::from(tmp);
    *list = heap.into_sorted_vec();
}
```

So, for a short while `*list` is made equal to an empty vector. In this case it's ok because creating and dropping empty `Vec`s is very cheap.

IIRC there is even a crate out there that helps borrowing some `*mutref` by value, without using a dummy value in-place during the borrow. But I can't find it right now. It would look something like this:

```
fn heapsort<T: Ord>(list: &mut Vec<T>) {
    borrow_by_value(list, |tmp| {
        BinaryHeap::from(tmp).into_sorted_vec()
    });
}
```

where `borrow_by_value` uses some unsafe code (probably `ptr::read`) to give you the `Vec` by value and will put a `Vec` back to `*list` with some more unsafe code (probably `ptr::write`). The actual implementation might be a little more complicated to protect you from panics somehow. I don't know. And if not, you should probably avoid using it after all.

Edit: The crate I was talking about is [take_mut](https://crates.io/crates/take_mut). There is even an [RFC](https://github.com/ticki/rfcs/blob/replace_with/text/0000-mem-replace-with.md) to add something like this to `std::mem`.

Comment: Is it preferable to do this instead of just `mem::swap(&mut list, &mut heap)` after creating the `BinaryHeap` (if `heapsort` consumed the `list`)?

Comment: @ljedrz: You mean compared to the assignment `*list = ...`? Well, you could do `mem::swap(list, &mut heap.into_sorted_vec())`. But why so complicated? The assignment is just fine. You could also do `mem::replace(list, heap.into_sorted_vec())` to "replace it back". But that's not going to be different from the assignment in the end since we don't care about the return value of this last replace.